# RFCOMM Connection refused because of pin

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez

i am having issues connecting to a serial to bluetooth device on my raspberry pi.

in bluetoothctl i scan for the ip and try to pair (after trusting) but i get rejected and i never get prompted for a pin.

i also tried

```
rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm1 <bt_addr> 1
```

i check the hci dump and see the hci event

```
HCI Command: PIN Code request
```

then right under that i see

```
HCI Command: PIN Code request Negative reply
```

but i never get and option to put in my pin. i have connected to other bluetooth devices without this issue but for some reason i'm seeing this on this item [enter link description here](http://www.usconverters.com/blutronium)

i'm using a more recent version of bluez so the hcid.conf doesn't exist anymore, and unfortunately most of my searches involved that file as a solution. how can i fix this with the more recent bluez versions? is there a way to inject that pin when i attempt to connect?

i am able to connect an android device and windows os and read data, but for some reason linux is giving me a problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to register the agent in bluetoothctl for prompting. You can try the following commands in order.

In short,

```
hciconfig hci0 up
systemctl start bluetooth
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# pairable on
[bluetooth]# agent NoInputNoOutput
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# scan off #after you found the device
[bluetooth]# trust 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
[bluetooth]# pair 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
[bluetooth]# connect 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
```

There are various possible options for "**agent**". Check the below log.

```
root@mx6q:~# hciconfig    
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:02:72:A9:B6:45  ACL MTU: 1021:7  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:1038 acl:0 sco:0 events:50 errors:0
    TX bytes:1405 acl:0 sco:0 commands:49 errors:0

root@mx6q:~# hciconfig hci0 up
root@mx6q:~# systemctl start bluetooth
root@mx6q:~# ps -ef | grep bluetooth
root       324     1  0 00:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/bluez5/bluetooth/bluetoothd
root       339   314  0 04:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep bluetooth
root@mx6q:~# 
root@mx6q:~# bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 00:02:72:A9:B6:45 BlueZ 5.33 [default]
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 00:02:72:A9:B6:45 Discoverable: yes
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent 
DisplayOnly      DisplayYesNo     KeyboardDisplay  KeyboardOnly     NoInputNoOutput  off              on               
[bluetooth]# agent NoInputNoOutput 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:02:72:A9:B6:45 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Parthiban
[bluetooth]# scan off
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 RSSI is nil
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Controller 00:02:72:A9:B6:45 Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# trust 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Trusted: yes
Changing 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
Attempting to pair with 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Modalias: usb:v05ACp12A0d0930
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacafe
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

Comment: Thank you Parthiban, i tried your suggestions but unfortunately i am still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you please share the output which you for while trying the above set of commands?